# How to add X-Content-Type-Options:nosniff to every Response

Tags: java, spring-boot, request

I have a spring-boot application. A recent Qualys scan report shows following security threat

```
    X-Content-Type-Options: Header missing
```

It has detected the following requests,

- https://bat.bing.com/bat.js
- https://cdn-pci.optimizely.com/js/199565681146.js
- https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js

But when I check the code, this parameter is already added through Spring Security. And  `x-content-type-options:nosniff` can be seen in all of the responses except thrid party service like above detected by Qualys.

**Rquests with `x-content-type-options:nosniff`**

[image]

**Requests without it**

[image]

How to add `x-content-type-options:nosniff` to above requests where it is missing. Please help.

Comment: I am confused. How do you want to modify requests to third-party resources through your Spring-Boot-Backend when the frontend directly calls the third-party? That doesn't make sense.